# How do I send data from C# textbox to a HTML textbox?

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I am working with a C# program which has a textbox `txtPath` and an HTML website that has another textbox `txtWebPath`. The website is written in JavaScript.

`txtPath` is being filled by `openFileDialog`, while `txtWebPath`is being filled via drag-and-drop. My goal is to have a button that sends `txtPath` value to  `txtWebPath`.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The only way is to statically generate a html file where you insert the data. Normally you want a server and something that generates the website dynamically, like ASP.NET.

Comment: Is the website opened in a completely separate browser, or do you display it in a WebBrowser control inside your c# application? If you are using a WebBrowser control, you should be able to do it via the WebBrowser control's JS bindings. If it is in a separate browser, you would somehow have to match up the web application to the c# application and use some server side api with e.g. SignalR to send data to the browser. This will be a lot more difficult, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using **WebSockets**: they connect a server (the C# program in your case) with a web browser (in Javascript).
You can find more about how you would write such programs here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server